# How to activate modal to open on all 3 buttons click and not just with one button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I Would like the modal to activate on click of all 3 buttons but can't seem to get it working. I have only managed to open dialog on first button click. I tried messing around with Javascript and adding different events but can't figure out, what am I doing wrong?

Also would need the modal to open on more buttons click in the future as we will be adding more content to the site.

```js
//  Get modal element
const modal = document.getElementById("simpleModal");
// Get open modal button
const modalBtn = document.getElementById("modalBtn");
// Get close btn
const closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBtn")[0];

// listen for open click
modalBtn.addEventListener("click", openModal);

// Listen for close click
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

// function to open modal
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// Function to close block
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#blog {
  background: #fff;
}

.blog-posts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blog-content {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

img {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

h6 {
  padding-top: 0.2rem;
}

h3 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #333;
}

.btn-light {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: modalOpen 1.5s;
}

.closeBtn {
  color: $dark-color;
  float: right;
  margin: 1rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="blog" class="text-center py-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="blog-posts">
    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button id="modalBtn" class="btn-light">READ MORE</button>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button id="modalBtn" class="btn-light">READ MORE</button>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button id="modalBtn" class="btn-light">READ MORE</button>
    </div>
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="closeBtn"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="simpleModal2" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="closeBtn"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you have duplicate IDs in your html. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You make error when you give same ID to the tree elements ! 
Id must be uniq! That point.

-To make it better use getElementsByClassName to get all element for attaching your event.

Also make specific name class because if you use default class than every element with that class name will attach event. We wanna attach event only for class name "readMore".

To pass arg i use custom attribute !

Here's corrected code :

```js
//  Get modal element
const modal = document.getElementById("simpleModal");
// Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("readMore");
// Get close btn
const closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBtn")[0];

for (var x=0; x < modalBtn.length; x++) {
  modalBtn[x].addEventListener("click", openModal);
}
 
// Listen for close click
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

// function to open modal
function openModal(event) {

  var content = "";
  var modalPreview = document.getElementById("modalPreview");
  if (event) {
   
    console.log("Look for target element" + event.target);
    console.log("Look for parent element" + event.target.parentNode);

    content = event.target.getAttribute("MyContent");
    
    console.log("Use some data from parent element" + event.target.parentNode.childNodes[0]);
    
    console.log("Use some data from parent element" + event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
    
    console.log("Use some data from parent element" + event.target.parentNode.childNodes[2]);
    
  
  }
  
  modal.style.display = "block";
  
  modalPreview.innerHTML = content;
  
  // += append
  modalPreview.appendChild(event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
  
}

// Function to close block
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#blog {
  background: #fff;
}

.blog-posts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blog-content {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.readMore {
  color: blue
}

img {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

h6 {
  padding-top: 0.2rem;
}

h3 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #333;
}

.btn-light {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: modalOpen 1.5s;
}

.closeBtn {
  color: $dark-color;
  float: right;
  margin: 1rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="blog" class="text-center py-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="blog-posts">
    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="https://maximumroulette.com/imgs/social/stack.png" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button MyContent=" TEXT 1 " id="modalBtn1" class="btn-light readMore">READ MORE</button>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="http://maximumroulette.com/imgs/social/linkedin.png" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button MyContent=" TEXT 2 " id="modalBtn2" class="btn-light readMore">READ MORE</button>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="http://maximumroulette.com/imgs/social/linkedin.png" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button MyContent=" TEXT 3 " id="modalBtn3" class="btn-light readMore">READ MORE</button>
    </div>
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="modalPreview"></div>
        <span class="closeBtn"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="simpleModal2" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="closeBtn"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @MPB And if the OP has 10 buttons ? You write `const modalBtnX = document.getElementById("modalBtnX"); modalBtnX.addEventListener("click", openModal);`  10 times ?

Comment: What do u mean by before negative comment please ?

Comment: And also i tried adding different content to the modal on pop up but the modal content is the same on every modal how do i add different content to each model ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic Do u know why I'm not able to post content differently on each modal?

Comment: I posted passing args! In console.log("Look for parent element" + event.target);  You can also access to the parent element and collect extra data !

Comment: @NikolaLukic i dont understand how im meant to do that? Im still pretty new to js

Comment: @NikolaLukic thank you made changed all working now!

Comment: @NikolaLukic how am i meant to add the content in the myContent surely i cant add images in there for the modal ?

Comment: I add example for adding parent element or data also !

Comment: Still does not answer my question dont think you understand what i mean I want the cards to still be the same but i want to be able to add content into the modal so i can add images and p tags into the modal

Comment: Maybe you want to pass some external data ? From other place with ajax or some json file or js object ?]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have duplicate id`s for the open buttons. Duplicate ID's are not valid HTML and this is exactly why. They can cause unwanted behavior.

`const modalBtn = document.getElementsByID("modalBtn");`

will select only the first occurence of the element with that ID. So just the first button.

You should add different ID's and a common class to the buttons. I added `modal-btn` class to each button that will open the modal. So it will select all those buttons.

Also HTML attributes should not be camelCase but dash case like `this-class`

```js
//  Get modal element
const modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
// Get open modal button
const modalBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-btn");
// Get close btn
const closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBtn");

// listen for open click
for (var i = 0; i < modalBtn.length; i++) {
  (function() {
    var j = i;
    modalBtn[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
      openModal(j)
    });
  })();

}


// Listen for close click
for (var i = 0; i < closeBtn.length; i++) {
  (function() {
    var j = i;
    closeBtn[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
      closeModal(j)
    });
  })();

}

// function to open modal
function openModal(j) {

  modal[j].style.display = "block";
}

// Function to close block
function closeModal(j) {
  modal[j].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#blog {
  background: #fff;
}

.blog-posts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blog-content {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

img {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

h6 {
  padding-top: 0.2rem;
}

h3 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #333;
}

.btn-light {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: modalOpen 1.5s;
}

.closeBtn {
  color: $dark-color;
  float: right;
  margin: 1rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="blog" class="text-center py-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="blog-posts">
    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button id="modalBtn" class="btn-light modal-btn">READ MORE</button>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button id="modalBtn2" class="btn-light modal-btn">READ MORE</button>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <button id="modalBtn3" class="btn-light modal-btn">READ MORE</button>
    </div>
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
      a
        <span class="closeBtn"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="simpleModal2" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
      b
        <span class="closeBtn"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="simpleModal3" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
      c
        <span class="closeBtn"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It worked but how do i edit the content differently on each element as when i type in my content it changed on all elements for the modal ?

Comment: @MPB well of course. Because all the time you open the same modal with ID `#simpleModal` .

Comment: I think i get what you mean i will try and edit myself as you may be able to tell i am still pretty new to javascript

Comment: I tried messing aroud with the Ids but i cant seem to find my answer ?

Comment: @MPB can you be more specific about your desired result ?

Comment: My desired result is so i can have content in the page just like this picture 

https://imgur.com/VNeLLlp

Comment: @MPB edited the answer with a solution. Unfortunately i didn't have time to make a full-proof solution but this should work in your case

Comment: Yes, it is working appreciate that a lot! Thank you saved me a lot of lines of code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write any script to open the model box. You can achieve your functionality using CSS only.

Here is the example.

```css
 #blog {
  background: #fff;
}

.blog-posts {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blog-content {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

img {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}

h6 {
  padding-top: 0.2rem;
}

h3 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #333;
}

.btn-light {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: modalOpen 1.5s;
}

.closeBtn {
  color: $dark-color;
  float: right;
  margin: 1rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.modelinput{display:none;}
.modelinput:checked + .modal_wrap{display:block;}
.btn{display:inline-block; padding:4px 10px; background:#cc3333; margin:auto; color:#fff; border-radius:3px;}
.btnwrap{text-align:center; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<section id="blog" class="text-center py-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="blog-posts">
    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <div class="btnwrap"><label class="btn" for="modelbox">Read More</label></div>
   
    </div>

    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <div class="btnwrap"><label class="btn" for="modelbox">Read More</label></div>
    </div>

    <div class="blog-content">
      <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
      <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
      <h3>How we can help you</h3>
      <div class="btnwrap"><label class="btn" for="modelbox">Read More</label></div>
    </div>
 
 <input type="checkbox" class="modelinput" id="modelbox" />
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal modal_wrap">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="closeBtn"><label for="modelbox"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></label></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

To read in detail https://www.growyourgk.com/css/simple-popup-without-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You used the same ID for all buttons, but IDs have to be unique. First you should change that.

Now you can decide, if you want to get elements by ID  (was now the fastest adjustment for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2kt6fqhz/2/) or by class name. If you get them by class name, it's pretty easy to set event listeners to as many buttons/elements as you want. I recommend the second option.

example:

```html
<div class="blog-content">
  <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
  <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
  <h3>How we can help you</h3>
  <button id="modalBtn1" class="btn-light">READ MORE</button>
</div>

<div class="blog-content">
  <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
  <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
  <h3>How we can help you</h3>
  <button id="modalBtn2" class="btn-light">READ MORE</button>
</div>

<div class="blog-content">
  <img src="./img/blog.jpg" alt="blog" />
  <h6>APRIL 2019</h6>
  <h3>How we can help you</h3>
  <button id="modalBtn3" class="btn-light">READ MORE</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Modifying modal content

In situation that you have many buttons that trigger the same modal with slightly different contents? Use event.relatedTarget and HTML data-* attributes to change the contents of the modal depending on button was clicked.

check [this link](https://coreui.io/docs/components/modal/)